# Is this Delphi Thread code correct?

Tags: multithreading, delphi, acrobat, twebbrowser

I know that Delphi threads have been discussed on many threads.  I tried reviewing them, but didn't find an answer to my question.

**Background:**
I have found that freeing a TWebBrowser can take 10+ second after the browser loaded up Adobe Acrobat Reader DC.  I think somehow it is checking for updates or something.  It is annoying when trying to close a form with a browser in it.

I thought perhaps I could have a background thread release the browser.  So I moved the browser variable to a global variable (privately stored in the implementation part of the unit).  Only one of these forms would be used at a time.  Then I tried to have a thread free it in the background.  It's not working as I would have expected.

Example code

```
interface
  TMyform = class(TForm)
    pnlBowserHolder: TPanel;
    procedure FormDestroy(Sender: TObject);
    procedure FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
  private
    //WebBrowser : TWebBrowser;  <-- moved to global variable
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

implementation

type
  TBackgroundBrowserKillerThread = class(TThread)
  public
    procedure Execute; override;
  end;

var
  WebBrowser : TWebBrowser;
  BrowserKillerThread : TBackgroundBrowserKillerThread;

procedure TfrmLabImageViewer.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  WebBrowser := TWebBrowser.Create(Self);
  TWinControl(WebBrowser).Parent := pnlBowserHolder;
  WebBrowser.Align := alClient;
end;

procedure TfrmLabImageViewer.FormDestroy(Sender: TObject);

begin
  BrowserKillerThread := TBackgroundBrowserKillerThread.Create(true);
  Application.ProcessMessages;
  BrowserKillerThread.Execute();  
  //WebBrowser.Free;
end;

procedure TBackgroundBrowserKillerThread.Execute();
begin
  TWinControl(WebBrowser).Parent := nil;
  FreeAndNil(WebBrowser);
  self.FreeOnTerminate := true;
  BrowserKillerThread := nil;  //free reference to thread, shouldn't affect ability of self to free itself (?)
end;
```

Questions:

- When I step through the FormDestroy code in debug mode, the line containing BrowserKillerThread.Execute(); takes 10 seconds still to execute.  I had thought that this would launch the other thread and return immediately.  But it doesn't.  Is my understanding wrong of what .execute does?  Or is something funny going on?
- Is what I am doing a bad thing?  I have read that the VCL is not thread safe, and that one can't/shouldn't access VCL objects from the other thread.  I was hoping that this wouldn't apply in this case since I am just freeing the object with no further interaction planned.
- If a thread free's itself upon termination, I assume this would leave my BrowserKillerThread pointer dangling.  So is it OK to assign nil to this as I do?
- Any suggestions on how to do this better?

Thanks so much in advance.

KT

Comment: This is never going to work. You can't access a VCL control of any sort from anywhere except the main thread, and you can't create it in one thread and destroy it in another. The code you've written doesn't change anything - the browser is still being destroyed by the main thread that owns it; you're just calling that code from your thread (which is wrong unless you're doing it via Synchronize).

Comment: Additionally... You might want to review all those threads again. I bet you haven't seen a single example having the execute method called from outside. Why? Because then the code in the execute method would run in the context of the thread that calls it.

Comment: I do not get the delay on closing the app you describe using TWebBrower + v.15.023 of Acro Reader DC. Can you give an example URL which provokes the delay for you?

Comment: Have you tried to navigate to about:blank before closing the form?

Comment: Thank you all for the helpful comments.  @MartnyA: I am opening a .pdf file stored on the local file system.

Comment: @MikeD: I did try navigating to about:blank, and that also took 10 seconds.    I am running this in a virtual machine.  I get the 10 second behavior there, though not in the host machine.  I have not installed the same version of Reader DC in both, so thought that was the difference.  But perhaps it is something to do with the VM.... Thanks again.

Comment: @KenWhite -- I was afraid this was going to be the case...

Comment: @Akyuz, yes, I am a definite newbie when it comes to threads.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> Is my understanding wrong of what .execute does??

Yes. This is not how you do threading. Generally, you first have to decide whether you need to do anything whatsoever with the thread after you have initially started it. If so, keep a reference, don't use `FreeOnTerminate`, and take care of the thread's destruction yourself after it has terminated. If you don't, don't keep a reference, set `FreeOnTerminate`, and send it off.

You would neither set `FreeOnTerminate` within a thread's execute, nor keep a global reference to a thread that has this set. You also don't start a thread by calling it's `Execute` method, but by either creating it non-suspended, or by calling `Start`. Just calling `Execute` doesn't actually start the thread, but executes this procedure within the context of the current thread, that's why it still takes 10 seconds.

Your example would become:

```
procedure TfrmLabImageViewer.FormDestroy(Sender: TObject);
  var BrowserKillerThread: TBackgroundBrowserKillerThread;
begin
  BrowserKillerThread := TBackgroundBrowserKillerThread.Create(true);
  BrowserKillerThread.FreeOnTerminate := true;
  BrowserKillerThread.Start;
end;

procedure TBackgroundBrowserKillerThread.Execute();
begin
  TWinControl(WebBrowser).Parent := nil;    // I don't think you need to nil the parent here, but probably does no harm
  FreeAndNil(WebBrowser);
end;
```

Now the threading is correct, but the logic is still wrong. As you already noticed you must not modify VCL objects from threads other than the main thread, this includes `Free`. You'd have to do this with `Synchronize`, which would defeat the purpose of threading.

I also think that the idea of killing the browser in a thread because otherwise it takes too long is only battling the symptoms, rather than the cause. I think it would be best to find out why that takes so long in the first place, and fix that, rather than trying to circumvent the issue this way. But this is outside of the scope of this question, if you have issues with that you should ask a separate question for this specific issue.

Comment: Great and helpful comment.  Thanks so much!

Comment: I have been playing around a bit with this.  I am using Delphi 10.  It looks like BrowserKillthread.Start should instead be BrowserKillthread.Resume.  There is no .Start in my version of Delphi.  Thanks again...

Comment: I decided to follow DNR's advice, esp with MartynA saying that he didn't experience a delay with closing, and went after the underlying cause.  I opened the Acrobat reader from the Windows Start Menu, and went into edit preferences.  I turned off every setting that I could find that made reference to talking to security servers etc etc, and made a safety exception for the folder that I was loading my .pdf's from (only viewing local files)... And sure enough, the 10 second delay is gone.  I'm writing this here in case anyone else has the same problems.  Thanks again everyone for the help.

Comment: Resume was deprecated in XE, and the documentation states you should use Start instead. If by Delphi 10 you mean one of the recent versions (Seattle or Berlin), you should have the start method.

Comment: I looked in Help->about and saw this version: Version 10.0.2166.28377   But I realized after posting that this is actually Delphi 2006.  Sorry for the confusion.